# Wordpress themes in cpanel

Tags: wordpress, themes, cpanel

I am here to ask a question regarding WordPress themes in c panel.
i installed WordPress in c panel and its working fine but I want to make the operation like, just by clicking on a theme name it should display the WordPress theme without going to admin panel i.e i am giving demo in my website about the themes which i have in my server.

it like www.something.com/templates by entering in this link i should get the list of templates for themes and by clicking on it i should get the demo of that theme.

Note : i installed wordpress in 'templates' folder in my Cpanel.

Hope I find solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use plugin like demo theme provider so use this WordPress plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/ijm-theme-bar/

Answer (score 0):

These can help.!

1. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-demo-builder/

> WP Demo Builder is the most powerful and simplest way to let your
>   potential customers truly experience your WordPress products. A game
>   changer and the first of its kind, our service helps you create
>   separate demo sites that allow your users to literally do everything
>   with it, both backend and frontend.

2. https://wordpress.org/plugins/demo-bar/

> This plugin helps to add demo bar for displaying your different theme
>   demos.